How can I limit the number of owner transactions?
I want to make a token that has the least developer's interference. So I am making a future of my token that limits the number of owner transactions.
I show necessary part of code.
contract Token is ERC20Interface, SafeMath {
    uint8 public _howManyTimesDoOwnerTriedToTransfer;
    address public _owner;

    constructor() {
        _owner = msg.sender;
        _howManyTimesDoOwnerTriedToTransfer = 0;
    }

    function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokens) private returns (bool success) {
        require(_howManyTimesDoOwnerTriedToTransfer < 5);
        if (msg.sender == _owner) {
                _howManyTimesDoOwnerTriedToTransfer++;
                balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
                balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
                return true;
        } else {
            balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
            balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
            return true;
        }
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint256 tokens) public override returns (bool success) {
        _transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokens) public override returns (bool success) {
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
        _transfer(from, to, tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }

It worked on BSC Testnet, but can this code limit token sells and disruption to liquidity pools?

Since the initial value of howManyTimesDoOwnerTriedToTransfer is 0, so I think you should put the condition of returning false as howManyTimesDoOwnerTriedToTransfer > 4 instead.

What Syed said. Two things, though:

I believe this is a terrible idea, for a number of  reasons. Mostly


It's misleading. This prevents the owner from transferring tokens to another wallet directly, but does not prevent them from selling tokens  or messing with the liquidity pool, and even if they wanted to transfer  to other wallets, they could by wrapping the token or going through a transfer helper contract.
If it was implemented in a way that would prevent what is described in the previous point, it would severely hinder the ability of the owner to maintain the token.


For clarity's sake, i believe you should revert the transaction instead of returning false, so in case the transfer fails because of this limitation, the owner has clear feedback on what happened, instead of a transaction that seemingly goes through, but does nothing.

